# Selenium Webdriver opens an extra driver window (intermittently)

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a strange issue with is not consistent, no trend observed. Whenever I run my webdriver code (see below)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

A driver/browser window opens up and the actions/steps go on as per my code but strangely, only sometimes an extra window opens up and follows same code/instructions.

My code prints/logs success/fail messages to console and I could see those messages only once even an extra browser window follows my code. And with the single **driver.quit()** command both the windows disappear.

I am using Firefox driver with Eclipse IDE driven by Java Client library.

Could anyone explain what happening with my code?

Comment: Are you using PageObjects with inheritance??

Comment: @AbhijeetVaikar I haven't had any problem with inheritance and Page Objects.  MCKiran, does a `driver.close()` make both windows disappear, or just one?  My guess is that some webpage you go to is opening up that page, and that its not your code.

Comment: @MCKiran Please provide some more info. Maybe more code.